How do I change the SERP title of my website in google results?
I managed to index my website successfully on GOOGLE, but I have an issue with the name of the search result snippet. I want it to show "Hamilton House Buyers," but instead, it displays hamiltonhousebuyers.ca. I have updated all schema for my website, I have added all code below for your reference, kindly check if anyone can help me out for the same, but it still doesn't show the title I want.
Here’s how it looks now:
hamiltonhousebuyers.ca instead of my website name.

What I want it to look like (I used inspect element for this):

Website name as search result snippet title
Can someone help me with this, please?
I used every schema likewise
https://docs.google.com/document/d/13WVNH4WgI_dnA6FOK9IzitTRGwgomOBlm9NkKbDzRjc/edit?usp=sharing
I have tried to find the line of HTML/JavaScript code using the inspect element on my page where hamiltonhousebuyers.ca is interfering with the website title and change it so that it doesn't overwrite the name of my website (Google search result snippet name). However, I found no such code. Therefore, nothing has changed. This site is being updated on the Carrot platform.

It's called a site name. Here is the official documentation on how you can influence them:
https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/site-names
It may take some time for Google to pick up on any changes, and there is no guarantee they will use your suggestions.

I have updated everything with this guideline and I have updated month ago, still it is not appearing my site name

That may mean Google is not confident with the brand name at this time.
